# Embed video with custom shortcode

Tags: wordpress, video, embed, vimeo, shortcode

In WordPress, how can I use the embed video feature via a custom shortcode?

I have tried the following, but that does not actually embed the video. It just adds an empty `<div class="aligncenter"></div>` to the html?

```
function shortcode_vimeo($atts) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "id"        => '', 
        "align"     => 'aligncenter'  
    ), $atts));  

    return '<div class="'.$align.'">' .  
        do_shortcode('[embed]http://www.vimeo.com/'.$id.'[/embed]')
    .'</div>';
}  

add_shortcode("vimeo", "shortcode_vimeo");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding videos seems to not work with `do_shortcode`. However, I have now found the following solution:

```
global $wp_embed;
$video_embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode('
    [embed]http://www.vimeo.com/'.$id.'[/embed]'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

IM USE http:// playerdrive. com  .. easy to use

The system draws a link that can repair links automatically expire. Available in both Jwplayer 6.x and jwplayer 7.x and prompted a broken link. Player skins with a beautiful 37 (for jwplayer 6.x) and 9 (for jwplayer 7.x), you have to choose. Animations can be pulled from Google's video was played before posters. It also supports applications on smartphones for all screen sizes. Protect Bringing in a given domain and. Can provide multiple site as needed.